# mailer preview not working because no routes match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actionmailer

My mailer is named send_invoice_mailer.rb (it works in dev and in prod).

I want to be able to preview the send_checkout_invoice function using the mailer preview.

routes.rb:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  #app routes
end
```

/spec/mailers/previews/send_invoice_preview.rb AND /test/mailers/previews/send_invoice_preview.rb (not sure which one is the correct one so I symlinked the file)

```
class SendInvoicePreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  
  def send_checkout_invoice
    #initializing foo
    SendInvoice.send_checkout_invoice(foo)
  end
end
```

When I go to: `/rails/mailers/send_invoice/send_checkout_invoice` I am redirected to `/fr/rails/mailers/send_invoice/send_checkout_invoice` with this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/fr/rails/mailers/send_invoice/send_checkout_invoice"
```

EDIT : rails is 4.2 and this is done in dev with passenger. App has been upgraded from previous rails versions multiple times.

EDIT 2 : /rails/mailers also does not work. Is it because of the locale scope?

Answer (score 4):

The location of the mailer previews directory can be configured using the preview_path option which has a default of test/mailers/previews:

Try updating your configuration path for action mailer preview as below:

```
config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/lib/mailer_previews"
```

which fails if test directory was not in production.

Check this link, this may helps

https://richonrails.com/articles/action-mailer-previews-in-ruby-on-rails-4-1

Comment: I also had to add ```config.action_mailer.show_previews = true``` in order to get it working

Comment: that link results in "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a few routes at the end of routes.rb that caught all requests. It works perfectly now.